# Debian - Change Key Output, but not Keymap

Tags: debian, keymap, openbox

I'm on Debian Squeeze using tilda and openbox, and as the source-engine-user I am, I mapped tilda to <kbd>~</kbd>. However, this creates problems when trying to press tilde normally, eg. for use in scripting. Is it possible to make <kbd>~</kbd> still open console, but make the system type a tilde character and NOT open the console when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> is pressed?

Comment: Have you tried to replace ` with grave in the keybind definition, i.e., write <keybind key="C-grave">
(...)
</keybind> ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is in fact possible, you have to create a custom keybinding for openbox. You can do what you want like so:

1. Open up the file `rc.xml` located at `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` in your favorite text editor.
2. Scroll down to the section where it says `<keyboard>`.
3. In that section, create a new key-binding with the format:

> ```
> <keybind key="...">
>  <action name="...">
>   <command>...</command>
>  </action>
> ```

So you need to set the keys for the binding, the action name and command. Here is an example of what you could use:

> ```
> <keybind key="C-`">
>  <action name="Execute">
>   <command>tilda</command>
>  </action>
> ```

This will tie up `tilda` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>` or ~</kbd> key. Allowing you to use the tilde with tilda, or just type it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the reverse of what I want to do; I want to simulate the press of the tilde key when Ctrl+Tilde is pressed, but have tilda toggled by Tilde alone.

Comment: Because I infrequently press the tilde key and I'm going for a quake-esque tilde-for-console setup.

Comment: Then I have no idea, sorry.